# Facebook-nodejs-business-sdk - Instagram ad creative without valid Instagram stream media ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have a Business Manager and an associated page and Instagram account all of which I am an admin of. Below is the json for adcreative creation

```
{
 'name': `Creative_${Date.now()}`,
 "object_story_spec": 
 {
  "page_id": page_id,
  "instagram_actor_id": instagram_actor_id,
  "link_data": 
    {
     "call_to_action": 
     {
      "type": "LEARN_MORE",
      "value": 
       {
        "link": linkurl,
       }
     },
    "link": linkurl,
    "message": message,
    "picture": pictureurl,
    "image_crops": {"100x100": [[0, 0],[800, 800]]},
    "description": description,
    "name": name,
   },
 },
'ad_format':'INSTAGRAM_STANDARD',
'platform_customizations':
  {
   "instagram": 
     {
      "image_url": pictureurl, 
      "image_crops": {"100x100": [[0, 0],[800, 800]]}
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Adcreative endpoint call using nodejs business sdk results in the following error

```
    error_user_title: 'Instagram ad creative without valid Instagram stream media ID',
    error_user_msg: 'Check your ad creative settings. Make sure that it has valid Instagram stream media ID.'
```

I am using facebook sdk and not standalone instagram api as I am able to find more answers for this issue on that topic.

Also, the picture url is a hosted image url with more than minimal Instagram dimensions. How to sort out this issue?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your profile pic is uploaded for instagram account. The issue may be because of media id of profile pic missing.